# Python class how to count object exists; not object created

Tags: python, class, object, count

> I need to count object exists those are created by specific class.
> I am aware of adding counter in **init**. But what if I overwrite an object later.
> For say
>
> emp_1 = Employee('Lucifer', 'male')
> emp_2 = Employee('Chloe', 'female')
> emp_2 = Employee('Dan', 'male')
>
> Here I called **init** method thrice but created only two objects. i.e I overwrite emp_2
>
> Can anyone help me this out

```
    #Trying to count employee exists
    class Employee:

        num_employee=0
        def __init__(self, n, a, g, s):
            self.name = n
            self.age = a
            self.gender = g
            self.pay = s

            Employee.num_employee+=1

    emp_1 = Employee('Lucifer', 27, 'male', 50000)
    emp_2 = Employee('Chloe', 23, 'female', 60000)
    emp_2 = Employee('Dan', 27, 'male', 40000)
    # emp_2 overwrote

    print(Employee.num_employee)
    # needed 2 getting 3 as output`
```

Comment: Using such unrelated variables is the root of your problem. Keep your data in order, use a list for example. Problem gone.

Comment: I think you should read about topic of garbage collector in python. Basically you cannot do what you want. If you need to keep this kind of count use a dictionary, but still you'll be able to overwrite the objects.

Comment: You still created 3 objects. One of them went out of scope when you reused the name `emp2`, but objects go out of scope for all sorts of reasons, mostly commonly if you create one during a function call and the object is bound only to a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object dies its `__del__` method is called. You can decrement your counter there:

```py
class Employee:
   def __del__(self):
      Employee.num_employee -= 1
```

But this would be a very fragile solution. You don't know when the garbage collector will run. Objects could die later than expected. You can [force the garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) algorithm to run but it is not a good practice.

I don't know what are you trying to do, but pretty sure a better solution would be a container that keeps your employee count.

This solution gets tricky if you copy your instances. Let's say you implement the proposed `__del__` method. Take a look at this code:

```py
import copy

emp_1 = Employee('Lucifer', 27, 'male', 50000) # Employee.num_employee = 1
emp_2 = copy.deepcopy(emp_1)  # Employee.num_employee = 1
emp_3 = copy.deepcopy(emp_1)  # Employee.num_employee = 1

emp_1 = None  # Employee.num_employee = 0
emp_2 = None  # Employee.num_employee = -1
emp_3 = None  # Employee.num_employee = -2

# Prints -2
print(Employee.num_employee)
```

To solve this you should increment your counter every time a new object is created. That is: in the `__new__` method. This will give a code like this:

```py
class Employee:

    num_employee = 0
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        Employee.num_employee += 1
        return super().__new__(cls)
        
    def __init__(self, n, a, g, s):
        self.name = n
        self.age = a
        self.gender = g
        self.pay = s
        
    def __del__(self):
        Employee.num_employee -= 1
```